# AngularJS send email with Mandrill with result from function

Tags: angularjs, mandrill

so i am trying to send a completed order form email with mandrill from my AngularJS delivery app... everything was working fine until i added a nested array within the function. so basically here is what i have. thanks for looking

here is the EmailController code snippet that is triggering the error

```
{
"name": "TOTAL",
"content": "$"+$scope.total(menu)+".00"
}
```

the function total(menu) works perfectly in the app to compute the total of all items and selected options.

here is the factory function

```
 OrderFactory.total = function(items){

    var itemTotal = 0;

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        var optionTotal = 0;
        var sizeTotal = 0;
        if (item.active) {
            itemTotal += item.qty * item.price;
            angular.forEach(item.flavors, function(option) {
                if (option.active) {
                    optionTotal += option.price;
                }
            });
            angular.forEach(item.sizes, function(option) {
                if (option.active) {
                    sizeTotal += option.price;
                }
            });
            itemTotal += optionTotal + sizeTotal;
        }
    });

    return itemTotal;

  };
```

what it is going through is an array menu[] that has two nested arrays sizes[] and flavors[] within.

both the EmailController and the OrderFunctions factory work outside of this scenario. What i need to figure out is why the total(menu) function is not providing a value to the EmailController.

here is the error i received in console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of null
at factory.js:55
at Object.r [as forEach] (angular.js:330)
at k.OrderFactory.total (factory.js:52)
at k.$scope.sendMail (controller.js:174)
at angular.js:12299
at f (angular.js:22903)
at k.$eval (angular.js:14353)
at k.$apply (angular.js:14451)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:22908)
at HTMLButtonElement.c (angular.js:2998)angular.js:11562 
(anonymous function)angular.js:8525 
(anonymous function)angular.js:14453 
k.$applyangular.js:22908 
(anonymous function)angular.js:2998 
c
```

any ideas??thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code doesn't handle exception condition, you should check object is null or not then only access inner property

```
        angular.forEach(item.flavors, function(option) {
            if (option && option.active) {
                optionTotal += option.price;
            }
        });
        angular.forEach(item.sizes, function(option) {
            if (option && option.active) {
                sizeTotal += option.price;
            }
        });
```

Comment: well i just noticed although it does allow the email to be sent it does not attached the computed total.. it just says $0.00. however in the app it is computed and displayed correctly..

Comment: could you add plunkr/fiddle with problem..& don't forget to do upvote.if it does helped you.

Comment: i never used those sites but i really need to figure this out so let me see if i can get one setup...

Comment: ok here is a plunkr...  http://plnkr.co/edit/7qntLNSImnOx9xNF6NUB?p=preview  i left the keys for mandrill in because i will change them once everything is all setup... so total(menu) and totalItems() does not pass the result to EmailController... but im glad i did this because there is a few thing i need help with and this will make it easier.. thanks for looking